# How to start a program without needing any logon screen on windows

Tags: boot

I want a program to run when windows starts full screen over the logon screen. I am trying to make a computer be able to start up then go straight to a program without the need to log in. Any ways i can do it?

Comment: Windows applications cannot be shown on the logon screen.

Comment: Unless you're in Kiosk mode.

Answer (score 0):

You need [Kiosk Mode](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-single-app). Do you have Pro, Enterprise, or Education? Then you can use Kiosk Mode.

When your kiosk is a local device that is not managed by Active Directory or Azure Active Directory, there is a default setting that enables automatic sign-in after a restart. That means that when the device restarts, the last signed-in user will be signed in automatically. If the last signed-in user is the kiosk account, the kiosk app will be launched automatically after the device restarts.